# Automate the execution of ExBPA?

Tags: exchange-2003, exchange-2010

It is possible to automate the Execution of EXBPA and save the XML to a database or otherwise process the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, two ways you could go about this.

1 - When running the ExBPA tool, at the stage when you connect to Active Directory click the arrow to drop down the option to enter additional credentials.  Enter some credentials that meet the minimum access level (the tool explains those) and the proceed through the ExBPA as normal.  Note when I did this I had to enter the domain name as the NetBIOS name not the FQDN.  When you get to the step to start the scan there is a link just below that to schedule the scan instead.  It adds a scheduled task visible in Task Scheduler.  The ouput XML file is saved to %appdata%\Microsoft\ExBPA for the account, eg C:\Users\administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\ExBPA

2 - The Test-SystemHealth cmdlet does basically the same job as the ExBPA and you could schedule that as well.